# Выраст?шь-узнаешь.

Tags: орфография

Я запуталась.
Какую букву поставить?

Comment: Для более конкретного ответа дополните предложение.

Если *вырастешь (кем, чем?) взрослым*, то через "Е".

Если *вырастишь (кого, чего?) растение*, то через "И".

По ссылке под ответом behemothus, написано с ошибкой, так как там подразумевается, что ребёнок будет расти сам, а не растить чего-либо.

Comment: Я не могу дополнить. Выражение законченное. 
А по другой ссылке?
http://iasora.beon.ru/
Там это заголовок.

Comment: Зависит от специфики сайта.
Если можно сказать *подрастёшь узнаешь*, то "Е".
Если - *подрастёт узнаешь* - "И"

Чаще такую конструкцию используют для того, чтобы сказать ребёнку, что знать ему что-то ещё не время, тогда через "Е", потому что он вырастЕт взрослым.
Но в принципе, вполне возможна ситуация, когда посадил непонятные семена, и что это за растение узнаешь только когда уже его взрастИшь.

В общем, это совет или вырасти (е), или вырастить (и), поэтому и однозначный ответ возможен лишь в контексте.

Comment: Специфика сайта? Я хочу знать, как написать выражение. Оно встерчается на каждом шагу. Не может же это зависеть от сайта?

Comment: Оно зависит от смысла фразы. А смысл зависит от контекста.

Comment: Разве смысл этой фразы может зависеть от контекста? 
Она же как пословица. "Поспешишь - людей насмешишь".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А значение какое? 
Вырастишь - от растить, вырастешь - от расти.
Скорее всего - второе, конечно.

Comment: - И что из него, оболтуса, вырастет?? 
- Вырастишь - узнаешь!)))

Comment: То есть и то и другое возможно?  
Мне тоже кажется, что должно быть вырастешь. 
А все пишут "вырастишь".
http://otvet.mail.ru/question/80852596
Это ошибка?

Comment: Да, в принципе возможно и то и другое. 
По ссылке - скорее всего ошибка. 
Я, кажется, Вас понял. Вопрос в том, что Вы считаете эту фразу устоявшейся и хотите знать, как её надо писать в общем случае, так?

Обычно - "Вырастешь - узнаешь", через Е. 

"Вырастишь - узнаешь" возможно только с подразумеваемым дополнением (вырастишь - что?) и почти исключительно - в ответ на прямой вопрос, содержащий упоминание об этом "что". Вырастишь (детей) - узнаешь. 
Если же "вырастешь" - то только "вырастешь сам - узнаешь". Именно в этом значении это обычно и употребляется как связанное сочетание.

Comment: А почему все-таки вопрос возник? Опишите ситуацию, если это, конечно, не абстрактный интерес.

Comment: Ага, про детей. Учительница подружиной племяшке объясняла - месяц разобраться не могли. А тут увидела и вспомнила. И да, тоже там что-то там говорилось про дополнения...

Answer (score 11):

Написание гласной определяется спряжением глагола. В словах вырастишь-вырастешь есть приставка ВЫ, которая перетягивает на себя ударение, а спряжения не меняет. Поэтому убираем в нужном слове приставку: вырастешь-растЁшь, вырастишь - растИшь. Пишем ту гласную, которая была в ударном окончании. А слово выбирайте, которое вам подходит по смыслу. Растить - растишь кого? что?(переходный глагол). Расти - растёшь (непереходный глагол).

Кем ты станешь, когда вырастЕшь? (растЁшь)
Когда вырастИшь цветок, дашь отросток? (ты растИшь цветок).

Comment: А как надо в этом выражении?

Comment: Так оно у Вас очень короткое, не совсем ясен контекст. Если сам вырастешь - е, если кого-то - И. Например, 

-Мама, почему...
-Вырастешь (т.е. подрастешь)- узнаешь.
Да Вам уже все подробно расписали...

Comment: :-) Ирина ГЛА, браво!!! Блондинки тоже интересуются языком...

Answer (score 1):

> Специфика сайта? Я хочу знать, как написать выражение. Оно встерчается на каждом шагу. Не может же это зависеть от сайта?

Элементарно. Задайте себе вопрос, IrinaGLA, **КТО вырастет?**

1. Если "ТЫ вырастешь -- узнаешь", то с надо писать с буквой **Е**.
2. Если "ЕГО (или ЕЁ) вырастишь -- узнаешь", то с буквой **И**.

По 2-ой фразе пример, если вы не поняли смысла.
Пожилая женщина говорит молодой: "Своего собственного ребёнка вырастишь, тогда узнаешь" .

Comment: Nikolja, я так понял, что рассуждать топикстартер умеет и смысл понимает, но не знает наперед, какой надо задать вопрос, типа "КТО вырастет" или "Кого вырастит"? 

Если фраза написана как есть, без контекста, вы какой вопрос зададите?
Лично я скорее всего "Что ты сделаешь?" (или "я сделаю"). Так что тут не катит. 
  
Может, конечно, и ошибаюсь, но, вроде, меня как раз поняли...

Comment: "топикстартер" - это апологетика русского языка. Теперь жду когда сократиться до "стартёра". Ай молодца, ребята. Ни малейшего усилия придумать или найти русское слово! Это гимн интеллекту участников форума "русского языка"!